# Order Posts by Taxonomy and Meta Value

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, meta-query, order

It's possible to [order posts by Meta Value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15477/custom-query-with-orderby-meta-value-of-custom-field).

It's possible to [order posts by more than one value](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

And thanks to the code below it's possible to order by taxonomy.

But how can I alter the code below to order by **taxonomy AND meta_value**?

**Added to functions.php**

```
function orderby_tax_clauses( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
global $wpdb;
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && $taxonomy == $wp_query->query['orderby']     ) {
            $clauses['join'] .=<<<SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb-    >term_relationships}.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
SQL;
            $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '{$taxonomy}' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
            $clauses['groupby'] = "object_id";
            $clauses['orderby'] = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC) ";
            $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ?     'ASC' : 'DESC';
        }
    }
    return $clauses;
}

    add_filter('posts_clauses', 'orderby_tax_clauses', 10, 2 );
```

**Added to index.php**

```
<?php $args = array(
'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
'orderby' => 'taxonomy_cat',
'order' => asc
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query-    >the_post(); ?>

etc. etc.
```

**Changing this doesn't work**

```
'orderby' => 'taxonomy_cat meta_value',
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, there is

```
if ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && $taxonomy == $wp_query->query['orderby']
```

that make your code not work with multiple order fields, because if you set

```
'orderby' => 'taxonomy_cat meta_value'
```

then `$taxonomy == $wp_query->query['orderby']` is never true.

In addition, I find that looping all taxonomy only with the aim to find the taxonomy to order by is low performant and not very reliable.

So I edited your code a little: when you want to order for a taxonomy your arg shouldbe something like:

```
'orderby' => 'taxonomy.taxonomy_cat'
```

thanks to the `'taxonomy.'` is easy recognize the taxonomy and there is no need to loop through all taxonomies.

After that, WordPress allow to pass only one argument as `'order'` argument, so when you pass multiple `'orderby'` arguments, the result can be not the expected one.

So I edited your code to accept an additional argument: `'ordertax'`. Sure this is optional, so if you not pass it, the 'order' argument is used. It is also ignored if `'orderby'` does not contain any taxonomy argument.
If you use multiple `'orderby'` arguemnts without passing `'ordertax'`, all the arguments are order based on `'order'` argument (or default 'DESC'), so using

```
'orderby' => 'taxonomy.taxonomy_cat meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

means `"ORDERBY taxonomy_cat ASC, meta_value ASC"`, using

```
'orderby' => 'taxonomy.taxonomy_cat meta_value',
'ordertax' => 'DESC'
'order' => 'ASC'
```

means `"ORDERBY taxonomy_cat DESC, meta_value ASC"`.

Now here the code:

```
function orderby_tax_clauses( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
  $orderby_arg = $wp_query->get('orderby');
  if ( ! empty( $orderby_arg ) && substr_count( $orderby_arg, 'taxonomy.' ) ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $bytax = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC)";
    $array = explode( ' ', $orderby_arg ); 
    if ( ! isset( $array[1] ) ) {
      $array = array( $bytax, "{$wpdb->posts}.post_date" );
      $taxonomy = str_replace( 'taxonomy.', '', $orderby_arg );
    } else {
      foreach ( $array as $i => $t ) {
        if ( substr_count( $t, 'taxonomy.' ) )  {
          $taxonomy = str_replace( 'taxonomy.', '', $t );
          $array[$i] = $bytax;
        } elseif ( $t === 'meta_value' || $t === 'meta_value_num' ) {
          $cast = ( $t === 'meta_value_num' ) ? 'SIGNED' : 'CHAR';
          $array[$i] = "CAST( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value AS {$cast} )";
        } else {
          $array[$i] = "{$wpdb->posts}.{$t}";
        }
      }
    }
    $order = strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) === 'ASC' ? ' ASC' : ' DESC';
    $ot = strtoupper( $wp_query->get('ordertax') );
    $ordertax = $ot === 'DESC' || $ot === 'ASC' ? " $ot" : " $order";
    $clauses['orderby'] = implode(', ',
      array_map( function($a) use ( $ordertax, $order ) {
        return ( strpos($a, 'GROUP_CONCAT') === 0 ) ? $a . $ordertax : $a . $order;
      }, $array )
    );
    $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ";
    $clauses['join'] .= "ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id";
    $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ";
    $clauses['join'] .= "USING (term_taxonomy_id)";
    $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)";
    $clauses['groupby'] = "object_id";
    $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '{$taxonomy}' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
  }
  return $clauses;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'custom_post_type',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_key'       => '_EventStartDate',
  'orderby'        => 'taxonomy.taxonomy_cat meta_value',
  'ordertax'       => 'ASC',
  'order'          => 'DESC'
);

add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'orderby_tax_clauses', 10, 2 );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'orderby_tax_clauses', 10, 2 );
```

---

Note that use my code (just like the yours) with a WP_Query containing a taxonomy query may break things... for this reason is important remove the filter after having used it.